# Как отобразить в ListView информацию из двух таблиц по id Android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, запрос

В таблице SCHED в ID_GROUP идет запись _id группы из таблицы GROUPS. Как мне через запрос query в ListView отобразить вместо ключа в ID_GROUP, запись из таблицы GROUPS по _id?

Код создания этих таблиц в БД:

```
 db.execSQL("create table GROUPS (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "NAME_OF_GROUP text);");
db.execSQL("create table SCHED (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "COUPLE text, "
            + "PREDMET text, "
            + "ID_GROUP text, "
            + "TYPE text, "
            + "CAB text, "
            + "DAY text, "
            + "WEEK text);");
```

Код отображения информации из БД в ListView:

```
cursor = db.query("SCHED", 
            new String[]{"_id", "COUPLE", "PREDMET", "ID_GROUP", "TYPE",      "CAB","DAY", "WEEK"},
            "DAY = ? AND WEEK = ?",
            new String[]{day, week },null, null, null);
   {day,week});
    CursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.list_row,
            cursor,
            new String[]{"COUPLE", "PREDMET", "ID_GROUP", "TYPE", "CAB"},
            new int[]{R.id.coupleView, R.id.predmetView, R.id.groupView, R.id.typeView, R.id.cabView },
            0);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Comment: используйте Left Join и все получится

Answer (score 3, accepted):

попробуйте создать `cursor` средствами `rawQuery`

```
private final String ZAPROS = "SELECT * FROM SCHED a INNER JOIN GROUPS b ON a.ID_GROUP =b._id WHERE a.DAY = ? AND a.WEEK = ?";

db.rawQuery(ZAPROS, ew String[]{day, week});
```

Comment: а CursorAdapter как должен при этом выглядеть?

Comment: @user212271 так же, только вместо `*` название полей укажите и `xml` под название группы подправьте